# Meteor.call access to authenticated User data?

Tags: security, authentication, meteor, user-input

In Meteor, on the Client, it's easy to determine the User.

The Client can send requests/parameters to the Server via `Meteor.call(params)`.

How do you get the logged in user data from the Server?

*(it would be insecure to pass from client to server)*

Answer (score 0):

Well that was easy.

`Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` are available on the server the same way they are on the client -- securely managed and verified by Meteor core.

Kudos Meteor team!

```
Meteor.methods({
  myFancyFunc1: function(args) {
    var user = Meteor.user();
  },
  myFancyFunc2: function(args) {
    var user = AbstractClass.getUser();
  }
});
AbstractClass = {
  getUser: function() {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      // are we initiated via DDP (with access to Auth, Meteor.call)
      var currentInvocation = DDP._CurrentInvocation.get();
      if (currentInvocation) {
        // return logged in user as passsed through
        return Meteor.user();
      }
      // we don't know the user details, return empty object instead
      return {};
    }
  }
};
```